# Applying rules on rules

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, replacement

So I tried taking a total derivative, with constants, but then the ouput had Dt[ ..., Constants -> ...] as an output. I tried to use a rule to remove it from tha output, but it did not work. See below. What am I doing wrong?

```
Dt[a x^2 + b y, x, Constants -> {a, b}]
Dt[a x^2 + b y, x, Constants -> {a, b}] /.{ Constants -> {a, b}} -> Null
```

Comment: I would do it like this: `Dt[a x^2 + b y, x, Constants -> {a, b}] /. 
 HoldPattern[Dt[x__, y_]] :> Dt[x]`.  I tried `Dt[a x^2 + b y, x, Constants -> {a, b}] /. (Constants -> {a, b}) -> 
  Null` first, but strangely enough, if you `Trace` the calculation, `Dt[x, y, Null]` evaluates to `Dt[Dt[x, y]]`, which I don't understand.

Answer (score 4):

```
SetAttributes[{a, b}, Constant]
Dt[a x^2 + b y, x]
```

> 2 a x + b Dt[y, x]

Comment: If you don't like making global definitions, you can use `Block[{a,b},SetAttributes[{a, b}, Constant]; Dt[a x^2 + b y, x]]`

Comment: @mikado, good suggestion for the OP to consider.

Answer (score 3):

A few additional ways to use [`ReplaceAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html):

```
Dt[a x^2 + b y, x, Constants -> {a, b}] /. _Rule -> {}
Dt[a x^2 + b y, x, Constants -> {a, b}] /. HoldPattern[Constants -> _] -> {}
Dt[a x^2 + b y, x, Constants -> {a, b}] /. p : (Constants -> _) -> {}
```

and [`Replace`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Replace.html):

```
Replace[Dt[a x^2 + b y, x, Constants -> {a, b}], _Rule -> {}, All]
Replace[Dt[a x^2 + b y, x, Constants -> {a, b}], (Constants -> _) -> {}, All}]
Replace[Dt[a x^2 + b y, x, Constants -> {a, b}], p:(Constants -> _) -> {}, All}]
Replace[Dt[a x^2 + b y, x, Constants -> {a, b}], HoldPattern[Constants -> _] -> {}, All}]
```

and [`DeleteCases`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteCases.html):

```
DeleteCases[Dt[a x^2 + b y, x, Constants -> {a, b}], _Rule, All]
DeleteCases[Dt[a x^2 + b y, x, Constants -> {a, b}], Constants -> _, All]
DeleteCases[Dt[a x^2 + b y, x, Constants -> {a, b}],  HoldPattern[Constants -> _], All]
```

all give

> 2 a x + b Dt[y, x]

Comment: +1 for the `DeleteCases` approach, which is probably the clearest in intent and will work for all heads. Regarding the other examples: Is there any specific reason why you give examples with unused named patterns and `HoldPattern`?

Comment: @LukasLang, thank you for the upvote. I think  `HoldPattern[foo] -> bar `  is the "canonical" method to make changes to the rule `foo`. I added others because they also work ( some in general, some only for the case in OP).

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
Dt[a x^2 + b y, x] /. {Dt[a, c_] -> 0, Dt[b, c_] -> 0}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to replace with [`Sequence[]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sequence.html), which does not rely on any behaviour specific to `Dt`<sup>1</sup>:

```
Dt[a x^2 + b y, x, Constants -> {a, b}] /. (Constants -> _) -> Sequence[]
(* 2 a x + b Dt[y, x] *)
```

Note the use of parentheses (`(...)`) instead of braces (`{...}`) around the r.h.s. of the rule.

<sup>1</sup> It will not work if the wrapping function (`Dt` here) has the[`SequenceHold`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SequenceHold.html) attribute

Answer (score 1):

It's a little bit hacky, but this works.

```
In[1]:=Dt[a x^2 + b y, x, Constants -> {a, b}] /. Rule[Constants, _] -> {}
Out[1]=2 a x + b Dt[y, x]
```

Weirdly, if you replace `Rule[Constants, _]` with something other than `{}` like `Nothing` or `None`, then the derivative term's inputs become reordered, like `Dt[y, Nothing, x]` (or whatever you replace it with).  If someone could explain that, it'd be very interesting.